# Deploying from Azure Devops to AWS machine behind VPN

Tags: amazon-ec2, azure-devops, vpn

We have our machines that we want to deploy to on AWS private subnet and we connect to them via VPN.

We want to use Azure Devops to build and deploy our code. Is there a way to deploy from Azure Devops to AWS machines through VPN?

Comment: Maybe more of a [sf] question than actual programming.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your machine can access `dev.azure.com`, then you can try [AWS Toolkit for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools) extension to work with AWS services.

Also, you can install one [self-agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) on your machine so that you can run the pipeline in your local environments.